# C# DNN Module Developement Add Action

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Hi I am trying to add an action Called "Add New Item" where the default "Edit Module" is. I am creating a new ascx Control named AddNewItem, also adding it to the menu with:

```
ModuleActionCollection Actions = new ModuleActionCollection();
Actions.Add(GetNextActionID(), 
            Localization.GetString("EditModule", this.LocalResourceFile),
            "", "", "", EditUrl(), false, 
            SecurityAccessLevel.Edit, true, false);
return Actions;
```

but I can't figure how to navigate from that menu to that ascx file? I looked at some same questions here and all over the net, but still can't manage it. will be glad if someone give's me a link with step by step or just gets me through the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add the "ModuleDefinition" in order for this to work. You can do this manually through the Host/Extensions page, which is what I typically do in my development environment, but to do it for Production you should add it to your .DNN file like so:

```
          <moduleControl>
            <controlKey>KeyToCall</controlKey>
  <controlSrc>DesktopModules/ModuleName/ControlName.ascx</controlSrc>
            <supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
            <controlTitle>Manage Content</controlTitle>
            <controlType>Edit</controlType>
            <iconFile />
            <helpUrl />
            <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
          </moduleControl>
```

When building the "URL" for that you can use EditUrl("KeyTocall").

You can add as many different "controls" as you want.

In your DEV environment, you can add that, recompile in RELEASE mode, and then install the module again through the host/extensions page and the change will be made to your dev environment as well.